# Connected Components Algorithm Output

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am currently implementing an algorithm for identifying connected components within an image. After performing adaptive thresholding I made another Mat variable called sub where I am updating its values such that the value containing them allows me to identify which pixels is connected to which pixel using the updating 'newObject' variable.

My expected output when I was finished with this was a relatively connected picture with various intensities where it can be seen which parts connected to which. My problem, however, is that my output which is the sub variable only shows a black image.

I've checked whether the values are actually changing by putting a print statement to check for the current value. I've also put various print statements in the if statements at one point and learned that they do enter the conditions where I change the values of the pixels in the sub variable.

My question is why is my output image a black image when I performed the imshow function on the sub variable. Sorry if I made a mistake somewhere, I am relatively new at this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < detected_edges.rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < detected_edges.cols; j++){
            if(detected_edges.at<uchar>(i,j) > 0){
                Point current = (i,j);
                if(i-1 < 0 && j-1 < 0){
                    newObject = newObject + 15;     //no values
                    sub.at<uchar>(current) = newObject;
                    printf("This is the value at this point: %u", sub.at<uchar>(current));
                }else if(i-1 >= 0 && j-1 < 0){
                    Point up = (i-1,j);
                    if(sub.at<uchar>(up) != 0){
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(up);                 //only up has value
                    }else{
                        newObject = newObject + 15;                                             //no values
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = newObject;
                    }
                }else if(i-1 < 0 && j-1 >= 0){
                    Point left = (i,j-1);
                    if(sub.at<uchar>(left) != 0){
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(left);               //only left has value
                    }else{
                        newObject = newObject + 15;                                 //no values
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = newObject;
                    }
                }else{
                    Point up = (i-1,j);
                    Point left = (i,j-1);
                    if(sub.at<uchar>(up) == 0 && sub.at<uchar>(left) == 0){

                        newObject = newObject + 15;                                             //no values
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = newObject;
                    }else if(sub.at<uchar>(up) == sub.at<uchar>(left)){             //same value
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(up);
                    }else if(sub.at<uchar>(up) != sub.at<uchar>(left) && (sub.at<uchar>(up) != 0 && sub.at<uchar>(left) != 0)){
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(up);                 //different values follow upper's value
                    }else if((sub.at<uchar>(up) != 0 && sub.at<uchar>(left) == 0)){
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(up);                 //only up has value
                    }else if(sub.at<uchar>(up) == 0 && sub.at<uchar>(left) != 0 ){
                        sub.at<uchar>(current) = sub.at<uchar>(left);               //only left has value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: I've noticed that only my first row in the 'sub' Mat variable is changing values for some reason even though the loop goes upto the last row of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the image was black was because I was going over the range of values for grayscale images (0-255) by making more objects. I performed a different implementation using a 2D array and have made an implementation of the algorithm.